# Setting width of a view as a fraction of the width of screen

Tags: android, user-interface

Can we set the width of a `view` as a fraction of the screen's width? If yes, the how?

Comment: see http://www.androidauthority.com/using-the-android-percent-support-library-630715/

Answer (score 0):

Here's my code

```
var ScreenWidth = (int)(Resources.DisplayMetrics.WidthPixels / Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density);
double prc = 0.35; 
double w = prc * ScreenWidth;  // get the 35 percent of the screen
LinearLayout.LayoutParams viewParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(Convert.ToInt32(w), ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent);
layout.LayoutParameters = viewParams;
```